# How to change combobox item text translation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to change ComboBox Items text translation? I have combobox where i select language. Application language is changing but it cant change text of checkbox items to selected language.

my **xaml**:

```
  <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Languages}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="LanguageName"  IsTabStop="False"/>
```

my **VM**:

```
   private ObservableCollection<LanguageSelector> _languages;

    public ObservableCollection<LanguageSelector> Languages
    {
        get { return _languages; }
        set
        {
            _languages = value;
        }
    }
    private LanguageSelector _slanguage;

    public LanguageSelector SLanguage
    {
        get { return _slanguage; }
        set
        {
            _slanguage = value;

            ChangeSelectedLang();
        }
    }


    private void ChangeSelectedLang()
    {

        if (SLanguage.Id == 1)
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
            SetLanguageDictionary();

        }
        else
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-EN");
            SetLanguageDictionary();

        }
    }

    private void SetLanguageDictionary()
    {
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
        {
            case "pl-PL":
                dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\LanguagePL.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                break;
            case "en-EN":
                dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\LanguageEN.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                break;
            default:
                dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\Language.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                break;
        }
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
        }

    }

    public void FillCombo()
    {
        Languages = new ObservableCollection<LanguageSelector>()
            {new LanguageSelector(){Id=1, LanguageName=Application.Current.FindResource("pl-PL") as string }
             ,new LanguageSelector(){Id=2, LanguageName=Application.Current.FindResource("en-EN") as string }
            };
        this.SLanguage = Languages.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

in my direcory i have:

```
<system:String x:Key="pl-PL">Polski</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="en-EN">Angielski</system:String>
```

i want switch combobox items text to selected language when i change it for EN ex. Polski to Polish

Comment: You need raise event PropertyChanged for property Languages

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

Comment: I try this but still don't work :( i use 

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }

end then:
 OnPropertyChanged("Languages"); in set property of Languages

Comment: You should call OnPropertyChanged("SLanguage"); in set property of SLanguage and set SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SLanguage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged}".

Comment: still not working. I have no idea why. I set SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SLanguage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" because OnPropertyChanged i get error :Requested value 'OnPropertyChanged' was not found i xaml.